# How to make a tapply style structure containing the N of multiple groups?

Tags: r, tapply

Probably very simple but I'm stuck right now: The following code basically returns a list of the Var1 means grouped by Var2 (Group1's mean: 5, Group2's mean: 7, Group3's mean: 4) that can be referred to by Mean_group[GroupX] How would I create a similar structure just showing how many cases there are in each group so I can access the N of each group like this:
N_of_each_group <- N of cases belonging to each group
N_of_each_group[GroupX]?

```
data <- data_frame(group = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "B", "B"),values = c(1,2,5,4,6,3,4))
Mean_group <- tapply(as.numeric(values, group, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

It's meant for a Shiny app and the N_of_each_group should be added into a text always matching the group the given user is part of. So if there are 10 people in group 1 and 15 people in group 2 user A from group 1 is supposed to see a text saying "There were 10 people in your group" and user B from group 2 sees a text that reads "There were 15 people in your group".

Comment: Your data structure is unclear, are `V1` and `V2` columns of a data.frame? Can you post data in `dput` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dplyr excels in this:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(mean_group=mean(values, na.rm=TRUE), n_group=n())

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  group mean_group n_group
  <chr>      <dbl>   <int>
1 A           2.5        2
2 B           3.75       4
3 C           5          1
```

Comment: do it as in the answer, it will work fine

Comment: Ahhhh, I just had a typo in the pipe.

Comment: glad I could help

Comment: Pleas check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I didn't get around to try it yet since I'm on holiday. I'll accept your answer when I did, I know the drill.

Comment: Now I did, thank you for your help and your patience :)